# Flutter: Mystery padding above keyboard when TimeDilation > 1.0

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I have a mystery padding above the keyboard when TimeDilation > 1.0 and I come to the screen with my keyboard on, from another screen.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClPJo.png)

The padding seems to be proportional to the time dilation when timeDilation >1.0 and < 3.0.  It seems to be constant at the same height for timeDilation values >= 3.0.

If I change the routing so that FirstScreen never gets generated, the bug is avoided.  Similarly, the bug can be worked around by forcing a screen redraw.

What is the cause and how do I need to change my code, to fix this bug?

**MRTC:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';

void main() async {
  // set the system top-level property [timeDilation] to control the animation speed
  timeDilation = 3.0;

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder?>{
          '/': (_) => FirstScreen(),
          '/screen2': (_) => SecondScreen(),
        };
        final builder = routes[settings.name]!;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: builder,
          settings: settings,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen>
    with RouteAware, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  FocusNode? focusNode;

  ValueNotifier<String>? _stringValueNotifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    this._stringValueNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>('');
    this._stringValueNotifier!.addListener(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stringValueNotifier?.dispose();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.focusNode = FocusNode();

    return Scaffold(
      body: KeyboardContent(
        focusNode: this.focusNode!,
        stringValueNotifier: this._stringValueNotifier!,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------

class KeyboardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final ValueNotifier<String> stringValueNotifier;

  /// A container for an on-screen keyboard
  /// The widget automatically gets rebuilt on value change, triggered
  /// when a keyboard button is pressed.
  KeyboardContent({
    required this.focusNode,
    required this.stringValueNotifier,
  });

  KeyboardActionsConfig _buildConfig(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget Function(FocusNode)> toolbarButtons = [];

    return KeyboardActionsConfig(
        keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL,
        keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200]!,
        //nextFocus: false,
        actions: [
          KeyboardActionsItem(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            displayActionBar: false,
            displayDoneButton: false,
            toolbarButtons: toolbarButtons,
            footerBuilder: (_) => CueKeyboard(),
          )
        ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!focusNode.hasPrimaryFocus) focusNode.requestFocus();
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
      child: KeyboardActions(
        config: _buildConfig(context),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              KeyboardCustomInput<String>(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                notifier: stringValueNotifier,
                builder: (context, keyboardTapVal, hasFocus) {
                  return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                      height: 800,
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                          color: Colors.green));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CueKeyboard extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  static final double _keyboardHeight = 184.0;

  CueKeyboard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CueKeyboardState createState() => _CueKeyboardState();

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(CueKeyboard._keyboardHeight);
}

class _CueKeyboardState extends State<CueKeyboard> {
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [Text("Keyboard")],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**flutter doctor**

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1466], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!
```

**flutter run --verbose**

```
$ flutter run --verbose
[  +53 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +84 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter/] git tag --points-at 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[        ] 2.8.1
[   +6 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +70 ms] executing: [C:\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +47 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +48 ms] executing: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +40 ms] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_phone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:11
[   +6 ms] C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +33 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +66 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[  +40 ms] Found plugin integration_test at C:\flutter\packages\integration_test\
[  +82 ms] Found plugin integration_test at C:\flutter\packages\integration_test\
[   +6 ms] Generating C:\Users\md844\source\repos\ucue_keyboard_bug\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +41 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +13 ms] Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
[  +24 ms] Initializing file store
[   +9 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +4 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents:
C:\Users\md844\source\repos\ucue_keyboard_bug\.dart_tool\package_config_subset}
[  +23 ms] Found plugin integration_test at C:\flutter\packages\integration_test\
[   +2 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
[   +1 ms] Skipping target: _composite
[   +2 ms] complete
[   +4 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
[   +3 ms] C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata
-DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill C:\Users\md844\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.f728f2b7\flutter_tool.9d976d\app.dill --packages
C:\Users\md844\source\repos\ucue_keyboard_bug\.dart_tool\package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation
--filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build\c075001b96339384a97db4862b8ab8db.cache.dill.track.dill --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy    
[   +7 ms] executing: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\aapt dump xmltree C:\Users\md844\source\repos\ucue_keyboard_bug\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk
AndroidManifest.xml
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\build-tools\32.0.0\aapt dump xmltree C:\Users\md844\source\repos\ucue_keyboard_bug\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk   
AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="0.0.1" (Raw: "0.0.1")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.debug" (Raw: "uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.debug")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x17
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1e
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="uCUE" (Raw: "uCUE")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:extractNativeLibs(0x010104ea)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=29)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.MainActivity" (Raw: "uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=43)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=53)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040002
                   E: intent-filter (line=57)
                     E: action (line=58)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=60)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=67)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
[   +8 ms] executing: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +13 ms] <- compile package:ucue_keyboard_bug/main.dart
[  +55 ms] --------- beginning of main
    
[...]

[  +49 ms] --------- beginning of main
           01-30 13:39:27.586 I/cmd     (25596): oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
[   +6 ms] executing: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.debug/uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.MainActivity
[  +34 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.debug/uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[ +360 ms] W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(25618): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration
steps.
[  +21 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:39329/Bg_xE12sSvQ=/
[        ] executing: C:\Users\md844\Android\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:39329
[  +16 ms] 60159
[        ] Forwarded host port 60159 to device port 39329 for Observatory
[   +4 ms] Caching compiled dill
[  +24 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:60159/Bg_xE12sSvQ=/
[ +252 ms] Launching a Dart Developer Service (DDS) instance at http://127.0.0.1:0, connecting to VM service at http://127.0.0.1:60159/Bg_xE12sSvQ=/.
[ +116 ms] DDS is listening at http://127.0.0.1:60162/57G22rjDLdI=/.
[  +43 ms] Successfully connected to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:60159/Bg_xE12sSvQ=/
[  +56 ms] DevFS: Creating new filesystem on the device (null)
[  +32 ms] DevFS: Created new filesystem on the device (file:///data/user/0/uk.co.cuedspeech.ucue.debug/code_cache/ucue_keyboard_bugULKJZB/ucue_keyboard_bug/)
[   +2 ms] Updating assets
[  +67 ms] Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
[   +1 ms] <- reset
[        ] Compiling dart to kernel with 0 updated files
[   +2 ms] <- recompile package:ucue_keyboard_bug/main.dart 027f4494-050d-4ec8-becc-6f960203b371
[        ] <- 027f4494-050d-4ec8-becc-6f960203b371
[ +114 ms] Updating files.
[        ] DevFS: Sync finished
[        ] Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86... (completed in 120ms)
[        ] Synced 0.0MB.
[   +1 ms] <- accept
[   +3 ms] Connected to _flutterView/0xe290b860.
[   +2 ms] Flutter run key commands.
[   +1 ms] r Hot reload. 
[        ] R Hot restart.
[        ] h List all available interactive commands.
[        ] d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
[        ] c Clear the screen
[        ] q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
[        ]  Running with sound null safety 
[        ] An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:60162/57G22rjDLdI=/
[ +491 ms] I/eech.ucue.debu(25618): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
[ +242 ms] The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:60162/57G22rjDLdI=/
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: ucue_keyboard_bug
description: Demo app showing the keyboard bug when time dialation=3

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 0.0.1+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  keyboard_actions: ^3.4.0
  pedantic:
  uuid: ^3.0.1

# Temporary dependencies
dependency_overrides:
 
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter

analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: you can use the inspector from developer tools to see where does the padding come from

Comment: It doesn't appear to be any of the widgets on the page, according to the widget inspector (unless I am missing something).

Comment: Can you please post an image? I can't understand how it's not any of the widgets in the page if it affects their appearance

Comment: Also I can't reproduce the issue from the code above, I don't see any text field to open the keyboard

Comment: See the link labelled 'Screenshot' in the post, for an image.  I've reduced the code to a minimal reproducible testcase, so I've removed the buttons from the keyboard - the keyboard is the grey rectangle with the text label 'keyboard'.  They keyboard opens automatically when the screen is drawn.

Comment: sorry I meant an image of the inspector, I saw the screenshot

Comment: Ah, sorry.

https://paste.pics/8c925245d4b1734af6c580fabb153da9